# mysql.connector.connect() function don't allow me to add any argument, why?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.7, mysql-python, mysql-connector

The `mysql.connector.connect()` function runs normally when I add nothing in it. But when I try to define the host argument, I was not allowed to do so and was told I gave too many keyword arguments - it's just annoying as I can not always use the default data!
I just did the same thing as the official documents or other people from Youtube, I don't understand why only I can not add even one argument to this function. :(
Why will this happen and how to solve it? Thanks!

```py
import mysql.connector


cnx = mysql.connector.connect() #It's normal!

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost') #TypeError: function takes at most 6 keyword arguments (7 given)
```

The complete trackback was shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\49280\Desktop\serverDir\transferManage.py", line 12, in <module>
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root') #TypeError: function takes at most 6 keyword arguments (7 given)

  File "C:\Users\49280\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 286, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\49280\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\49280\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1108, in connect
    self._open_connection()

  File "C:\Users\49280\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 211, in _open_connection
    plugin_dir=self._plugin_dir,

TypeError: function takes at most 6 keyword arguments (7 given)
```

Comment: Do you mean `user='root'` instead of `host='root'`?

Comment: Oh sorry for the mistake in the example code but it still didn't work and reported the same error when I try user='root' or host='localhost'. Only it works when I run mysql.connector.connect() without any argument added.

Comment: Please post the complete traceback.

Comment: I have edited the question and the complete traceback was added.